# dynamically added html-elements not known by jquery/js also with .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

These form is dynamically added to the document:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   name:<input type="text" name="name" /> <br/>
   <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

and the jquery/js function doesnt work for it.

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on( "submit", function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop normal submission
        alert("submit");
```

If i add the form direct to the document instead of dynamically then it works. Whats wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296530/jquery-onclick-vs-click-and-delegateclick and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679432/jquery-event-delegation  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements

Comment: Thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
$(function() {
        $('form').on( "submit", function(e) {
```

to

```
$(document).on( "submit", 'form', function(e) {
```

Comment: I would recommend looking at a better target element personally.. This will technically run that function for every single form element within the document. It might not be a problem in your case, but always best to follow best practice where possible. See a Q just like this I answered earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257890/jquery-click-on-now-triggering-close-using-load/37257960?noredirect=1#comment62043525_37257960

Comment: Yes i want to add more forms dynamically and i need to know from which table they are, i could write the tablename as id of the form. But i dont like to write multiple times the same js-function. Is it possible to get the id of the form which is actually submitted without catching it over theyr id at function-call?

Comment: If they are all in tables, could you not do `$('table').on( "submit", 'form', function(e) { `? Then you should be able to use `e.target.id` for the id of the form. Listening on tables is at least an improvement on using the document.

Comment: Good idea but doesn't work for me and i don't know why. I have a table and if you click on a row there is da slidedown under the row in which i add a form with a table inside. So thats my "edit" of each row. I need to know from chich table it is to add multiple tables on one page. If i do $('table').on... or $('form').on... or $('td').on... nothing happens.

Comment: var contentPanelId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
alert(contentPanelId); this give me the id of the form

Comment: What point in the code are you getting that ID? When it is created?

Comment: Dynamically if you click on an row in a table I echo ' <form id="'.$tablename.'" ...>'; under the selected row.